# SCA (Service Component Architecture) alternative

Tags: integration, soa, sca, oasis, apache-tuscany

Looks like the Apache Tuscany Project has been retired. Not sure what that really means, but there are still quite some Opensource and Vendor specific implementation using SCA. If this standard isn't supported anymore is there any other alternative out there ? Also I don't get why SCA hasn't been used as the main binding for Microservices, because they are kind of the same as SCA Components/Modules.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Oracle blocked passage of the specifications at OASIS (you will have to ask them why since they never explained the reason for their vote to the specification committee).

Fabric3 (fabric3.org) is an active open source project that supports SCA and is used for a number of microservice-based architectures. You may want to look at that.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly SCA didn't hit the industry as the council was expecting and that's why they decided to archive it. Currently WebSphere Application Server 8.5 supports it, but since the Apache project is not supported anymore I cannot guarantee long term support.

As for services, my advise is that you go with the standard well-known specs like SOAP and REST.

Comment: IBM's Integration Bus (IIB) and IBM BPM are still actively using SCA Bindings, same for Oracle Fusion. As for opensource implementation Fabric3, switchyward and Anypoint Softmule are using the SCA concept. So it's not really dead.

Answer (score 0):

SCA is now dead. The world has moved on to gRPC.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer. With reference will be more convincing.

Comment: You can improve the quality of your answer by explaining *why* you think `SCA` is now dead and the world has now moved onto `gRPC`.  Please support your argument with references to other sources that advance this argument.